# Overwrite data in file written with DataOutputStream - IndexOutOfBoundsException - What's the "off" parameter in "write" method?

Tags: java

I'm using `RandomAccessFile`'s method `write` to achieve that, but the following code is throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException` at the 3rd line:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(this.dbFileName, "rw");
raf.seek(position);
raf.write(data[0].getBytes(), 0, FieldLength.NAME.value);
raf.write(data[1].getBytes(), 0, FieldLength.LOCATION.value);
// etc
```

`FieldLength.NAME` is an enum of `int` type.

What's the `off` parameter in method `write(byte[] b, int off, int len)`? Documentation only says "off - the start offset in the data". Is it a position relative to the file's pointer? (Which was changed in the previous line, with execution of the method `seek(long pos)`)

I didn't find any similar method in `DataOutputStream` class.

The JDK is 6.

Comment: How did you populated data array?

Comment: The offset is to skip some bytes of your `byte` array.

Comment: The file is read with `DataInputStream`, then I put the "field" values in a map with their record number and the data itself. When reading this map, the program populates an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is either that data array does not have two elements (getting exception on third line implicates it would not have even one element) or the return of getBytes() does not return enough data. You need to check for this. The second problem might also be fixed by filling-up the data - probably strings - accordingly.

Comment: It's an array with 32 elements, and I verified it with debugging. Also, there do is data being returned. I'll try user987339's hint in a moment.

Comment: Data, yes, there are some, ok. But are there enough data? I mean, is data[0].getBytes().length >= FieldLength.NAME.value ?

Comment: If you are trying to write fixed-format file and have strings in the data array you need to fill-up the strings up to required length, i.e FieldLength.NAME.value or FieldLength.LOCATION.value respectively. Btw it looks like Java certified developer assignment ;-)

Comment: The other hint says the same as I do ;-)

Comment: The "field" has size 64, but data length is always lower than that. Guess that's the problem then. I'll use StringBuilder to fill the remaining spaces (already did that with insertion of data). Yes, it's Java assignment.

Comment: It was really a "field size" matter. It's updating the wrong record, though, and a 5KB file has now more than 10KB "magically". But that's a different issue, so I marked this one solved.